# Most efficent way to remove all children in a Javascript object, at any level, with a certain name?

Tags: javascript

Given an object like so, which won't always have the exact same structure,

```
data: {
    deleteMe: true,
    level1: {
         level2: {
             deleteMe: true,
             level3: {
                 level4: {
                     level5: {
                         deleteMe: true
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

What is the most efficent way to loop though this entire object, in Javascript, that will allow me to delete all the properties named `deleteMe`.

Comment: Do you mean "the most efficient way", or "some way"? What have you tried?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. What's the point of that object if the structure is not convention?

Comment: @SterlingArcher For example, think of objects as a generalised tree in this case. Why enforce a structural schema? Case in point, the trie data structure. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just iterate recursively and remove

```
function remove(obj, what) {
    (function stuff(o) {
        for (var key in o) 
            key && key == what ? delete o[key] : stuff(o[key]);
    })(obj);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ddp09zvm/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Traverse the object recursively:

```
function remove_deleteMe(o) {
    if (o && typeof o === 'object') {
        delete o.deleteMe;
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function(k) { remove_deleteMe(o[k]); });
    }
}
```

Or, if you would prefer to specify the name of the property to be deleted:

```
function removeProp(o, propName) {
    if (o && typeof o === 'object') {
        delete o[propName];
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function(k) { removeProp(o[k], propName); });
    }
}

removeProp(data, 'deleteMe');
```

Actually @adeneo's approach is more compact and readable, taking advantage of the fact that `for...in` works on non-objects. Taking some liberties:

```
function removeProp(o, propName) {
    for (var k in o) {
        if (k === propname) delete o[k]; 
        removeProp(o[k], propName);
    }
}
```